# Not able to open the camera from the WebView in appcelerator

Tags: javascript, android, webview, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Currently i am working on load a url inside a webview, by using that same url in browser, it's able to access the camera "by showing a alert to access camera", but when i using the same url inside a webview in an application by appcelerator not able to access the camera . If guide me to solve this .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You can fire Ti event  from `webview` and inside the event listener access the camera

Ex :-

**webview file**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            Ti.App.addEventListener("app:fromTitanium", function(e) {
                alert(e.message);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="Ti.App.fireEvent('app:fromWebView', { message: 'event fired from WebView, handled in Titanium' });">fromWebView</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Js file**

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
var webview = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    url: 'logging.html'
});
var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: 'fromTitanium',
    height: '50dp',
    width: '130dp'
});
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    Ti.App.fireEvent('app:fromTitanium', { message: 'event fired from Titanium, handled in WebView' });
});
Ti.App.addEventListener('app:fromWebView', function(e) {
    alert(e.message);
});
win.add(webview);
win.add(button);
win.open();
```

More details http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Communication_Between_WebViews_and_Titanium

Comment: Hi abada thanks for your suggestion but i didn't mean that . I am using a enterprise url . When i hit that url in browser it asks to access the permission for access the camera but when i use that url in webview then it is not able to access the camera, shows video disabled .

Comment: Can you write this url ?

Comment: @SauravSenapati so it seems that the WebView can ask for (HTML5) device permissions but somehow doesn't get them. That looks like a bug. Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.